# Load Form Element Values Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get dynamic values in a form with jQuery?

For example I have this:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action"contact.php" class="ajaxForm">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>Email:</label>     
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send!"/>
</form>
```

In js:

```
$(".ajaxForm").send(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr("action");
});
```

I want to get var name=value with some loop like .each but the code is only reading inputs/textarea/select data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain input/textarea/select values in a form with jQuery.

```
$(".ajaxForm").send(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr("action");
    var its = $(this).find('input, textarea, select');
    its.each(function(){
         console.log($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.children()`

```
$(".ajaxForm").send(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr("action");
    $(this).children('input').each(function() { // Loop over all  the children
                                                // that are input elements
           console.log( $(this).val() );
                       OR

           console.log( this.value );
    });

});
```